# Find m365 meeting organizer using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

We have an issue with people who move on from our workplace, meaning they end the employement for some reason. When they do, we move their user to a OU outside normal operations and disable it.

The usual problem that occurs is that the user that quit booked a few meetings in conference rooms. Now that they have moved away from the company we get stuck with unbookable rooms as they are taken.

What I want to do is a PowerShell script that looks through each conference room and looks if this person has organized any meetings and, if so, cancel that meeting.

My problem that is I can't find the organizer of meetings. I have tried both the ExchangeOnlineManagement and Microsoft.Graph modules, but I can't figure out how to find the organizer for a meeting.

I have tried the CmdLet's from ExchangeOnlineManagement and Microsoft.Graph.Calendar. But I haven't gotten anywhere with it.

Answer (score 0):

Get-CalendarDiagnosticObjects may help, you may specify a time period,  you may run it for the disabled user's mailbox, or the resource mailbox.

Get-CalendarDiagnosticObjects -Identity "Pedro Pizarro" -Subject "Team Lunch" -StartDate 7/1/2018 -EndDate 7/31/2018 | Export-Csv "C:\My Documents\Team Lunch Meeting.csv" -NoTypeInformation

AppointmentState

CalendarLogTriggerAction (create may be filtered out)

ResponseType

ResponsibleUserName

fields may be investigated.

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-calendardiagnosticobjects?view=exchange-ps